# oj-select-one show all list of values in the drop down

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-jet

By default oj-select-one displays only the first 15 values and then forces the user to search for remainder.

Is there a way to make oj-select-one show all values in the drop down list without having to use search ?

I tried using minimumResultsForSearch as below, this but this does not help.

```html
    <oj-select-one id="select1"  
        options="[[dataProvider]]" 
        value="{{selectVal}}"
        minimumResultsForSearch="50"
        style="max-width:20em">
    </oj-select-one>
```

I am using the example in http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=selectOne&demo=dataFiltering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You chose the right attribute but used the wrong syntax. It should be `minimum-results-for-search` instead of `minimumResultsForSearch`

```
<oj-select-one id="select1"  
    options="[[dataProvider]]" 
    value="{{selectVal}}"
    minimum-results-for-search="50"
    style="max-width:20em">
</oj-select-one>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried that but it still does not work. I am using the example in http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=selectOne&demo=dataFiltering

Comment: I see. It's because of the `FilteredDataProvider` file that they are importing and using. It's overriding `minimum-results-for-search`. Do you need to use that? If not, I suggest you use this example http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=selectOne&demo=minimumResultsForSearch and use `minimum-results-for-search` attribute. It will work properly over there

Comment: unfortunately I need to use this with a data provider which cannot be replaced with an array. I did notice that this feature is extended by JET from JQuery, not sure if we can set the value from javascript.

Comment: Able to get it work by using ko.observableArray([]) insted of oj.ArrayDataProvider to populate the list of values. --Thanks

Comment: FYI I ran into this exact problem using oracle jet in VBCS. I put in an SR since we are paying customers and they told us it is a bug and they don't have any plans on fixing it .....

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli oh I see! That's interesting... May I ask how long ago was that?

Comment: Last week. I have two issues. The minimum results attribute is ignored, and when I populated an oj select with a business object (using a rest call essentially) if I use a filter criterion it filters the 15 displayed in the drop down but ignores the filtering when I start typing